# Downloading multiple files from a URL Directory with a similar name

Tags: python

I am trying to download multiple *.csv* files from an url directory with similar names (*AB_daily.csv*, *BC_daily.csv*, etc.). However, each file is stored in different folders in the directory. I know there is a  way to use a loop to extract the files, but I can't figure out how to do it with Beautiful Soup or glob. Do you have any suggestions? I've also used `pandas.read_csv()` to look for shortcuts as I'm just trying to concatenate the files together later. Thank you.

URL Directory: https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/

```
import os
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        target = [f"{url[:20]}{item['href']}" for item in soup.select(
            "a[href$='AB_daily_hydrometric.csv']")
    
    
    for x in target:
            print(f"Downloading {x}")
            r = req.get(x)
            name = x.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
            with open(name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)

main('https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv')
```

Comment: Use Breadth or Depth Traversal - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode

Comment: You want to parse the response from `https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv` for the link for each state. Then parse the responses for each of those links to get the link for the `daily` and `hourly` directories. Then parse the response from each to get the links to each csv file. Alternatively, since you know all the states in Canada and you don't expect them to change frequently, you can just hardcode them in a list in your code and iterate over that list instead of the first step. You can't just `glob` a server you don't own because security.

Answer (score 0):

```
# For this specific task this will work:
import os
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
csv_links = []
links = ["AB/", "BC/", "MB/", "NB/", "NL/", "NS/", "NT/", "NU/" "ON/", " PE/", "QC/", "SK/", "YT/"]
def main(url):
with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
 for item in links:
        r_daily = BeautifulSoup(req.get(url + item + "daily/").content, 'html.parser')
        r_hourly = BeautifulSoup(req.get(url + item + "hourly/").content, 'html.parser')
        for item_d in r_daily.find_all('a'):
            if ".csv" in item_d.get('href'):
                csv_links.append(url + item + "daily/" +item_d.get('href')) 
        for item_h in r_hourly.find_all('a'):
            if ".csv" in item_h.get('href'):
                csv_links.append(url + item + "hourly/" + item_h.get('href')) 
    for x in csv_links:
        print(f"Downloading {x}")
        r = req.get(x)
        name = x.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)

main('https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.

Comment: Thank you for you help!

Comment: Also, I don't think this was a poor question. I searched this forum and other examples to figure out a solution but decided to post a question